Approximating the eigenvalues of the multiplication of two matrix
I want to give the upper bound of the eigenvalue decay of a matrix $C=A^{-1} B$, to be more specific the upper bound of $\frac{\lambda_j}{\lambda_1}$ for each j. $\lambda_1\geq\lambda_2\geq\cdots\geq\lambda_n$ are eigenvalues of $C=AB$, where A,B are symmetric and are very similar, which means that $-\eta B+\eta cI\preceq A-B\preceq \eta B+\eta cI$ for a small $1>\eta>0$ and some constant $c$. I guess their eigenvector are very close but I cannot give a rigorous explanation.

$A^{-1} B = I + A^{-1}(B-A)$ so all eigenvalues are $1+\mu_i$ where $|\mu_i|\le|A^{-1}(B-A)|\le |A^{-1}||B-A|$. Now can you use your hypothesis?

if you want to work with random matrices, as the tag suggests, you should specify it in the text
